# How to create a doPOST on JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm making a connection to a database using JDBC, however, I want to create a query like this: SELECT idCows FROM cows where Name = "someVariable".

In this case, "someVariable" is a String that I will get from a form in my HTML, so the question is how can I retrieve that variable and set it to the query so every time I search a name it will bring me the right answer.

My code looks like this:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connector {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Farm";

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "admin", "admin123");

        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT idCows FROM cows WHERE Name = "+name);

        while(rs.next()) {

            String n = rs.getString("Name");

            System.out.println(n);
        }

        stat.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please search for "prepareStatement" and "bind variables"

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You must put the variable in single quotes like

```
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT idCows FROM cows WHERE Name = '"+name+"'");
```

Or, much better, use a PreparedStatement.

```
PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idCows FROM cows WHERE Name = ?");
stat.setString(1, name);
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
```

Then do

```
String n = rs.getString("idCows");
```

instead of `"Name`"

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to check this solution right away.